# SQL Developer prompt for substitute variable - how to avoid?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, substitution

I have two scripts master.sql category.sql and I am setting value for substitute variable in master.sql and use it in category value to export data in csv file - the file name is stored in substitute variable. Here is my code:

master.sql

```
set feedback off;
set serveroutput on;
SET SQLFORMAT csv;
var CatCode char(5) ;
COL fileName NEW_VALUE csvFile noprint

exec :CatCode := '18';
select ('c:\temp\CatCodes_' ||  trim(:CatCode) || '.csv') fileName from dual;
@category.sql;

exec :CatCode := '19';
select ('c:\temp\CatCodes_' ||  trim(:CatCode) || '.csv') fileName from dual;
```

category.sql

```
set termout off
spool &csvFile 
SELECT Catgry_ID, Category_Name FROM Categories WHERE Catgry_ID = :CatCode;
spool off;
set termout off
```

When I run script master.sql (F5) on one machine it just works fine and creates two different csv files in c:\temp folder but when I run same script on different machine it prompts for csvFile! I am sure it should be some setting issue but I can't find it. I checked DEFINE setting on machine where it does not prompt, show define "&" (hex 26) and on another one it shows define "&". Is there anything else do I need to set to ignore prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Write this in your script

```
set define off
```

If you are using substitution variables, you can set define to some other character(ensure that character is not used elsewhere)

```
set define <<Character>>
```

Example:

```
set define #
```

Comment: Dont you think set define off will ignore substitution of csvFile in  spool &csvFile ?

Comment: As I mentioned in the 2nd part of answer, you can use any other character instead of & to display prompt.

Comment: I tried changing '&' to '#' by passing set define #, but no change in result. Its working on one machine and not on other.

Comment: This worked like a Magic.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing SQL Developer and reinstalling it and it worked :)